# How to Merge Cells Across Based on Cell's Value for Multiple Rows

Tags: excel, vba

Every time I try to run my macro, the first section surrounded by the LIRCounter runs just fine, but Excel returns a "Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error" and the Debug highlights my Range(...).Merge sections on the rest of my macro.

I have tried reformatting the range by removing the .Merge, the Counter variable, and rewriting my entire code, but I can't narrow down what part of the range is causing the error.

```
Sub MergeCells()

    Dim FirstRow As Long
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim TechnicalDataSheet As Worksheet
    Dim LIRCounter As Long
    Dim ETCounter As Long
    Dim ETCounter2 As Long

    FirstRow = 15
    LastRow = 44

    Set TechnicalDataSheet = Worksheets("Technical Data")

    With TechnicalDataSheet
        For LIRCounter = FirstRow To LastRow
            If Cells(LIRCounter, 19).Value = Not IsEmpty(Cells(LIRCounter, 19)) Then
            Else
                Range("U" & LIRCounter, "Z" & LIRCounter).Merge
            End If
            If Cells(LIRCounter, 19).Value = Not IsEmpty(Cells(LIRCounter, 19)) Then
            Else
                Range("U" & LIRCounter, "Z" & LIRCounter) = "N/A"
            End If
        Next LIRCounter

        For ETCounter = FirstRow To LastRow
            If Cells(ETCounter, 3).Value = "Structural" Then
                Range("D" & ETCounter, "L" & ETCounter).Merge
            End If
            If Cells(ETCounter, 3).Value = "Structural" Then
                Range("D" & ETCounter, "L" & ETCounter) = "N/A - Structural"
            End If
        Next ETCounter

        For ETCounter2 = FirstRow To LastRow
            If Cells(ETCounter2, 3).Value = "Structural" Then
                Range("O" & ETCounter2, "Z" & ETCounter2).Merge
            End If
            If Cells(ETCounter2, 3).Value = "Structural" Then
                Range("O" & ETCounter2, "Z" & ETCounter2) = "N/A - Structural"
            End If
        Next ETCounter2
    End With
End Sub
```

The expected result is if "Structural" is selected from the dropdown menu in cell C15, then the cells D15:L15 merge into one cell, and the cells O15:Z15 merge into one cell.  And the same goes for every row down to row 44. When the Macro is run, it just returns "Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error" and no cells are merged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've written "With TechnicalDataSheet"  But your lines below refer to Cells not .Cells
and so pick up the activesheet and not your desired target. Add the full stops in front of all Cells references

Comment: That worked, thanks! I'm new to VBA and don't know simple stuff like this and your help is greatly appreciated!